# Can I change the port of my MLflow tracking server?

Tags: http, port, mlflow, mlops

I would like to know if I can change the port of my MLflow server.

By default it is running on port 5000, but my company's VPN only allows HTTP (port 80) and HTTPS (port 443) traffic.

This might be a very beginner's question, but is it possible, and if yes, is there any problem on running the MLflow server on port 83 (HTTP) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that by passing the `-p port_number` command-line switch when starting MLflow server (see [docs](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/cli.html#cmdoption-mlflow-server-p)). Please note, that to be able to use ports below 1024, the server needs to be run as root.